# Passing URI prefix to createSwitchNavigator function for Deep Linking with react-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have a fairly straight forward set up with react-navigation that utilizes a switch navigator which accepts a param signedIn to set the initial route which looks like this:

```
const uriPrefix =
  Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? 'myApp://myApp/'
    : 'myApp://'

const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => (
  createSwitchNavigator({
    LoginNav,
    AllNav: { screen: AllNav, uriPrefix, path: '' }
  }, {
    initialRouteName: signedIn ? 'AllNav' : 'LoginNav',
  })
);
```

I then call this in RootContainer:

```
 const Nav = Navigation(isLoggedIn);
 return (
    <Nav />
  )
```

On iOS this works fine with the uriPrefix and I am able to link to the screens using `Linking.openURL()` with the link.

On Android it does not work. I am able to make it work on Android without using the switchNavigator and just exporting LoginNav and AllNav, but I still need a switchNavigator.

I followed the instructions here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html, but am unable to pass uriPrefix in the way they define. I found that at least for iOS, I was able to define that inside of my switchNavigator, but it just does not work the same for me on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug in react-navigation:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5027
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4913

There's some workaround there that might help, I ended up changing all my navigation into stack navigation to support deep linking =(